# Cannot connect to my wired network

Tags: networking, wired

I just installed Ubuntu (18.04) on my other computer. It is not a laptop, so no Wi-Fi ability, but only wired. It finds the wired network, but it cannot connect to the Internet. The problem just started when I installed Ubuntu, and replaced Windows 10. It worked fine until then.

Comment: Please, paste `ip a` command line output to your original question.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Please describe your cabling from the computer to the router/modem.